# PhoneGap - Abrir WhatsApp "whatsapp://send?" IOS 10

Tags: html, ios, apache-cordova, whatsapp

Até a ultima versão do iOS 9 quando queria compartilhar algo pelo whatsapp eu podia usar o link:

```
whatsapp://send?text=mensagem
```

em uma tag `<a>` ou `window.open` no js.
Porém nos iOS 10 isto parou de funcionar, ao clicar no link ele não executa nada, nem sequer abre o whatsapp.

Comment: Mas não é necessário criar um popup para isso, bastaria criar um link não? Todavia não tenho iOS 10 para testar :/

Comment: No navegador Safari em iOS 10 o link funciona?

Comment: Funciona sim ! Só não funciona dentro da aplicação feita no cordova.

Comment: Entendi, então deve ser algo que falta liberar no webview ou nas permissões, não uso cordova mas vou tentar ver se consigo descobrir, posta o código do webView e das permissões por favor.

Comment: Troquei para não abrir no webview, e sim no navegador padrão, agora ele abre o whats porém não envia o text

Comment: Sem código fica dificil saber exatamente o que você fez

Comment: Consegui resolver, vou colocar a solução aqui ![

Answer (score 2):

Consegui resolver isso da seguinte maneira.

na página em que havia o botão que envia o conteúdo para o whatsapp, estava assim :

```
<a href='whatsapp://send'  data-text='' data-href='http://playfcapp.com.br/gol/?id=".$regis_01['id']."' class='wa_btn wa_btn_l' style='display:none'><div id='social_whatsapp' style='background:url(http://playfcapp.com.br/gol/img/social_whatsapp.png) center center no-repeat #10c246; background-size:contain; height:38px; margin-top:10px;'></div></a>
```

porém não no IOS 10 o botão não funcionava (ficava sem ação), somente quando o link era whatsapp://send.
Então tentei enviar primeiro para uma pagina web onde o usuário seria redirecionado para o whatsapp, não funcionou pois o app tentava abrir esta página pelo Webview do Phonegap, quando enviei para abrir pelo browser default ai funcionou:

```
window.open('"endereço da página de redirecionamento"', '_system', 'location=no');
```

o _system faz toda a diferença, pois o webview não consegue abrir o whatsapp.

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa usar https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=seu-numero&text=texto-que-deseja
É possível usar apenas a função phone ou apenas text
Isso vai chamar o app tanto no android quanto ios e funciona sim no 10

Se você utiliza site em wordpress, criei algo para deixar um botão flutuante em todas as páginas de forma fácil já redirecionando para o número que deseja.
Se quiser conferir: [WhatsApp Chat WP](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-whatsapp-chat/)